# Regex: how to get the "width" and "height" value from this string which is right after "bitwise" value?

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

Lets say I have this string:

```
,"mimeType":"video/mp4;+codecs=\"avc1.42001E,+mp4a.40.2\"","bitrate":353051,"width":640,"height":320,"lastModified":"1543659519195688","contentLength":"24469560","quality":"medium","fps":24,"qualityLabel":"360p","projectionType":"RECTANGULAR","averageBitrate":35300;codecs=\"avc1.64001F,+mp4a.40.2\"","bitrate":987359,"width":1280,"height":640,"lastModified":"1543660211977003","quality":"hd720","fps":24,"qualityLabel":"720p","projectionType":"RECTANGULAR
```

I need to extract all the pair values for width and height which are right after a `"bitrate"` string.

Notice that the string has width, height twice. I need to get both pairs:

```
"bitrate":353051,"width":640,"height":320

"bitrate":987359,"width":1280,"height":640
```

Notice that I only need to get the ones which are immediately followed by `"bitrate"` value. If there's no `"bitrate"` value right before, then I don't want it.

So the answer should be:

```
640,320
1280,640
```

I have pasted the string here:

https://regex101.com/r/VXAyvV/2

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/VXAyvV/3

Comment: @Nick thanks! I updated the string in yours with an extra width, height pair without bitwise before it: https://regex101.com/r/VXAyvV/4  Btw, if you post this as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex, which will only match `width` and `height` when they immediately follow a value for `bitrate`:

```
"bitrate":\d+,"width":(\d+),"height":(\d+)
```

The width and height will be captured in group 1 and 2 respectively.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/VXAyvV/5)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regular expression.

```
"bitrate":(?=.*?"width":(?<width>\d+))(?=.*?"height":(?<height>\d+))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EbRBEM/1/)

I tested it with the PCRE (PHP) regex engine, but it should work with all engines that support positive lookaheads, which is most regex engines.

I used named capture groups but that is not necessary as the width is always captured first (after `"bitrate"` is matched), even if it follows the height in the string. There can be intervening fields between `"bitrate"` and `"width"` and `"bitrate"` and `"height"`.

Consider the following string.

`"qual":"360p","bitrate":987359,"wt":90,"width":1280,"fps":24,"height":640,"last":"154"`

When matched against the regex the capture group named `width` will hold `"1280"` and the capture group `height` will hold `"640"`.

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
"bitrate":       match '"bitrate":'
(?=              begin a positive lookahead
  .*?            lazily match 0+ chars other than newlines
  "width":       match '"width":'
  (?<width>\d+)  match 1+ digits and save to capture group 'width'
)                end positive lookahead
(?=              begin a positive lookahead
  .*?            lazily match 0+ chars other than newlines
  "height":      match '"height":'
  (?<height>\d+) match 1+ digits and save to capture group 'height'
)                end positive lookahead
```